# Как в C# получить первый и последний элементы динамического массива?

Tags: c#, массивы, arraylist, динамические-массивы

В Java есть `ArrayList`, а там `myList.get(0)` и `myList.get(myList.size()-1)`.
А вот в C# вообще не могу такое найти (`item32[]` не работает). Какие есть варианты?

Мне нужно запомнить координаты первого и, возможно, последнего прикосновения мыши.

Нужен ли динамический массив для решения подобной задачи? Как можно решить её иначе?

Comment: а зачем вам массив, если нужно хранить только две позиции мыши? про остальное VladD уже написал.

Comment: Первый индекс массива - начальная позиция, последний - последняя))) костыль такой - не мог сообразить, как еще сохранить эти координаты. Да и сейчас не могу). Спасибо за ответы, теперь буду думать, как взять координаты прикосновений. Ну или мыши (прикосновения вроде беру, но нужно на устройстве проверить - с мышью не хотят. Или я взял неправильно). А как еще можно их сохранить? Причем меня интересует только осьY

Comment: а просто 2 переменных,  first и last например, чем не угодили?

Comment: В LibGdx у меня было следующее: if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) myArrayList.add(Gdx.input.getY()); и я даже не знаю, что ставить в эти first и last - в любом случае оба этих значения равнялись последнему getY()

Comment: а промежуточные значения потом использовались где-то?

Comment: В LibGdx у меня было следующее: if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) myArrayList.add(Gdx.input.getY()); и я даже не знаю, что ставить в эти first и last - в любом случае оба этих значения равнялись последнему getY(). Нет, промежуточные вообще не нужны. Главная проблема в сохранении первого прикосновения. И что именно нужно сохранять - этот getY() заменяет все значения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В C# вы должны использовать `List<int>`, массивы обычно недостаточно удобны.

Первый элемент `list.First()`, последний `list.Last()`.

Не забудьте `using System.Linq`.

---

Дополнительный бонус по сравнению с Java: вам не нужна обёртка наподобие `Integer` на `int`.

---

Если вас интересуют мышиные координаты, то вам понадобится, понятно, `List<Point>` (или в какой там структуре данных к вам приходят координаты мыши).