# Как обратиться к последнему элементу массива? C#

Tags: c#, массивы, случайные-числа

Нужно заменить первый и последний элемент массива на единицу, остальные равны нулю. Количество элементов массива задается рандомно

Comment: подумайте, как получить позицию последнего элемента, зная длину массива?

Comment: Вы можете получить длинну массива обратившись к его свойству `.Length`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в C# получить первый и последний элементы динамического массива?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519170/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Answer (score 2):

В новых версия C# можно писать так: `array[^1]` означает первый элемент с конца.
Или использовать LINQ: `array.Last()`.

Comment: ласт лучше всего, что бы не выйти за рамки массива

Comment: @Andrew `Last` на пустом массиве все равно киданет исключение, поэтому в любом случае нужно делать проверку

Comment: ласт возвращает нуллейбл, если мне не изменяет память

Comment: А, то LastOrDefault или как-то так

Comment: @Andrew это должно быть `LastOrDefault`

Comment: Это с какой версии такой синтаксис доступен? Не то, чтобы собрался использовать, чисто для общей эрудиции на собеседовании где попадётся.

Comment: @AK C# 8 https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges

Answer (score 0):

`Array.Length - 1`. Единичка, потому что нумерация с нуля. Вот и всё!

Comment: ну и проверка, что длина массива больше нуля :)

Comment: верно подмечено)